# Is there a way to get images from backend to frontend once they're separate modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm developing a system with vue and node, my backend and my frontend are listening from different ports, until now it wasn't a problem and I was able to exchange data through them, but now I need to get relative paths that are in a database to render images from a backend folder in my frontend. My question is: Is there a way to do it or I should try to save these files in my frontend folder?

These images are uploaded through a form where I register products, each product has one photo slot. I save the photo in a folder and get the path to the database.

I already tried to use in the path the address I'm running my backend i.e.: "http://localhost:3000/" + path and it didn't work :(

Comment: Is the folder at your backend publicly accessible? How do you serve those images? Are you using express.static middleware https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html ?

Comment: my file system is like this:  frontend and a backend folder, each one is the root for frontend and backend application respectively, the folder "upload" is inside "backend", this one I made public, although the backend folder I didn't, is there any problem?

Comment: So if you place a file named abc.xyz in the upload folder, you should be able to access it at http://localhost:3000/abc.xyz if that doesn't work, then the upload folder is not public. In that case can you add the code which should make the folder public to you question?

Comment: It works! Thanks ^^